# как правильно указать диапазон генерации для (0;1) с тремя знаками после запятой?

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

как правильно указать диапазон генерации для (0;1) с тремя знаками после запятой используя функцию rand()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я верно понял, что вам нужно -

```
(rand()%1000)/1000.0
```

Еще вариант - округлять до трех знаков, типа

```
round(rand()*1000.0/RAND_MAX)/1000.0
```

Comment: `rand()%1000` дает неравномерное распределение.

Comment: @bipll Не думаю, что это критично для данной программы...

Comment: Истинная правда.

Answer (score 3):

А почему бы вам не использовать библиотеку `random`, которая доступна с 11 стандарта? К примеру, если вам нужно генерировать числа в диапазоне от 0 до 1 это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 generator{rd()};
  std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist{0, 1};

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    std::cout << dist(generator) << std::endl;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Ну а для того, чтобы установить вывод именно с тремя знаками можно воспользоваться `iomanip` и установть `std::setprecision(3)`

Comment: Поправка : Вывод 3х знаков и наличии их я думаю все же разные вещи)

Comment: @Maggot не могу себе представить где кроме вывода имеет значение наличие именно фиксированного количества знаков после запятой.

Comment: ну все зависит от вычислений - 0.999 * 0.999 = 0.998001 и 0.99909 * 0.99909 = 0.9981808281 - и боевая часть упала не туда)))

Comment: @Maggot вот только 1) результат по первых трёх тот же, 2) не следует забывать о погрешности при подсчёте во флотах

Comment: я написал о реально прецеденте произошедшим в 2000-х годах в РФ))))

Comment: @Maggot вот только какое это отношение имеет к текущей ситуации? Взгляните на вопрос: случайные числа - какая разница сколько там будет знаков после запятой? Отразится на вычислениях? Ну так числа и так случайные... Более чем уверен, что ТС нужна точность в три знака именно для вывода